# CENTOS:Problems accesing to a remote machine port

Tags: centos, network-interface, vmware, telnet

I was trying to access to a specified port of remote machine from my CENTOS machine and I am not able to connect.

If I write `telnet remote_machine 666` I have no response.

The client machine is a vmware virtual machine where where the `firewalld` and `iptables` are stopped.

In the same vmware server I have another virtual machine (this one in ubuntu), that is able to connect to 666 port of remote machine.

Another curious things are that:

With a `nmap` scan, from Ubuntu machine I can see remote 666 port as open, while from CENTOS machine 666 port is filtered.
In vmware client I can see ubuntu network adapter type(where it works) is defined as flexible while CENTOS one is defined as `VMXNET 3`

What could happen?

Comment: Please check your firewall logs on the source computer to see whether the outgoing connection is blocked (something like `dmesg | grep -i firewall | tail -20` or so).

Comment: In the machine where it doesn't work it appears the message: [   14.376811] Bridge firewalling registered.
In the machine where it works, nothing appears

Comment: OK, please post the output of `brctl show` on the machine where it does not work.

Comment: No lines are posted (only headers are shown).bridge name   bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces

Comment: Can you `ping` the machine?

Comment: Ping command doesnt work to the server one from both machines. With Nmap command i am able to access the server machine but it appears the 666 port as filtered from the CENTOS one

Comment: I think this might have to do with kernel routing options on the host.  Please try `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` on both hosts Ubuntu/CentOS and if CentOS differs do `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

Comment: In both cases, return 0 value